# Automatically add standard strings either side of variable strings

Tags: function, google-sheets, string-concatenation

I have a library of flags online that I use in a spreadsheet. The current function looks like this:

```
=image("http://www.website.com/images/Flags/us.png", 3)
```

I would like to apply a rule or a function to an entire column so that I just need to write `us` and it automatically adds this before:

`=image("http://www.website.com/images/Flags/`

and this after:

`.png", 3)`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly. If you put the two 'standard components' into say B1 and C1 as shown below then:

```
=B$1&A3&C$1
```

should serve to concatenate the three elements to suit provided the `us` is in A3. The formula can be copied down to wrap the standard components around other values in ColumnA, if required:

[image: SO14461482 example]